# Need Help on Sql recursive query

Tags: t-sql, datetime, recursive-query

I need to simulate end date/time for a production order. Ex:the production order take 4:55 hours but it may have 1 or 2 break and maybe 1 lunch time depend hours needed and current time. I need to calculate all off time between current time and production time. I just no idea if a resursive query will be useful.

```
create table [TeamBreak]
(
  Team int ,
  StartBreak datetime,
  EndBreak datetime 
);

insert into [TeamBreak] values
(1, '1900-01-01 09:00', '1900-01-01 09:15'),
(1, '1900-01-01 12:00', '1900-01-01 12:30'),
(1, '1900-01-01 14:15', '1900-01-01 14:30'),
(2, '1900-01-01 18:15', '1900-01-01 18:30'),
(2, '1900-01-01 01:15', '1900-01-01 01:30')

DECLARE @start AS datetime='2019-01-31 7:00'
DECLARE @end AS datetime='2019-01-31 11:50' --prodction end date without break

SELECT SUM(iif(@end BETWEEN t.startbreak AND t.endbreak, DATEDIFF(n,t.startbreak,@end), DATEDIFF(n,t.startbreak,t.endbreak))) AS newtime
FROM teambreak AS t
WHERE CAST(t.startbreak AS time) 
    BETWEEN CAST(@start AS time) AND CAST(@end AS time) 
    OR CAST(t.endbreak AS time) BETWEEN CAST(@start as time) AND CAST(@end AS time)
```

Btw, break must be in datetime type instead of time because of Access front application doesn't support time type .

Let's start to 7h00am (first end date production without break is 11h55 or 4h55 to produce), break at 9am-9h15am lunch time 12pm-12:30pm.
The result should be 40 minutes to add production end date instead of 15 minutes.

So it will be 7h00+4h55=11h55 + 15minutes(break)=12h10 enddate(but impossible because of lunch time), so the real end date will be 12:40pm(because 12h-12:30) is off).
the. My first result end date is 12:10pm, but the good one should be 12:40pm

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: When you create a new question and add the SQL tag, a  large suggestion is shown to you that you should add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax between them differs. Please [edit] your question to do so. Until you do, any answer is guesswork that may not work for your specific needs, which would make it a waste of both your time and that of the person writing the answer. If you want us to help you, you need to provide the necessary information.

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking for

Comment: do you mean you want to find break time in minutes between `2019-01-31 7:00` and `2019-01-31 11:50`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a simple way with a while...not a resurcive CTE

First While it found a break time at 9:15-9:30.
it add 15 minutes to 11:55. now the end date is 12:10.
second loop it found the lunch time criteria
it add 30 minutes to 12:10. now the end date is 12:40 as I wanted

```
declare @start as datetime='2019-01-31 07:00'    
declare @end as datetime='2019-01-31 11:55' --prudction end date without break1
declare @newEndDate as datetime    
declare @newAddTime as int=0    
declare @newAddTimeTotal as int=0
set @newEndDate=@end    
while( 1=1)    
begin    
    select @newAddTime=     
    coalesce(sum    
    (    
    case 
        when 
            CAST(@start AS TIME) between cast(t.startbreak  as time ) and     cast(t.endbreak as time) then datediff(n, CAST(@start AS TIME),cast(t.endbreak as time))
        else 
            datediff(n, CAST(t.startbreak AS TIME),cast(t.endbreak as time))
        end),0)
    ,@start=max(t.endbreak) 
    from teambreak t        
    where (cast(@start as time) <cast (t.endbreak as time)  and  cast(@end as time)>     cast(t.startbreak as time))        
    set @end =dateadd(n,@newAddTime,@end);
set  @newAddTimeTotal= @newAddTimeTotal+@newAddTime
    if @newAddTime=0
    break;
end

select @newAddTimeTotal,@end
```